# Rows not getting persisted when using bulk inserts in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am trying to insert many rows in both the while loops. My understanding is that I have to create a separate new transient instance in the loop body in the transaction.

From my experience not creating a separate transient instance (transient instance outside loop body) inserts at the very least the one row, that being the last row. Do I need to use `save` only once here before committing transaction?

Are the use of `flush()` and `clear()` right in this case?

I am relatively new to hibernate.I would be thankful for any help or pointing me in the right direction.

Please excuse my flouting the camel case convention for variables and methods.

```
public boolean addVariableHonorariumDetails(Monthly_variable_honorarium_processing mvhp
                                             , Monthly_variable_group_honorarium_processing mvghp
                                             , Monthlyvariablecompid compositeID)
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();   
    Transaction tx = null;
    String ccyymm = mvhp.getMvhp().getVariable_monthly_ccyy()+mvhp.getMvhp().getVariable_monthly_month();

    try
    {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        // ctrl query

        M_control_table mct = (M_control_table) session.createQuery("from M_control_table").uniqueResult(); //single result

        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"Select c.Booklet_type, SUM(c.End_Leaf -  c.Start_Leaf +1) as No_of_Coupons from m_coupon_sale c where date_format(c.Booklet_Sale_Date, '%Y%m') = :string and c.Booklet_type in ('GR','PI') group by c.Booklet_Type")
                             .addScalar("c.Booklet_type", Hibernate.STRING)
                             .addScalar("No_of_Coupons", Hibernate.STRING)
                             .setString("string", ccyymm);

        ScrollableResults results = query.scroll();

        Integer sumTotalOfPayment = 0;
        while ( results.next() )
        {
            Object[] row = results.get();

            mvghp.setMvhpgroup(new Monthlyvariablecompid(mvhp.getMvhp().getVariable_monthly_month()
                              , mvhp.getMvhp().getVariable_monthly_ccyy()
                              , row[0].toString())
                              );

            mvghp.setNo_of_items(row[1].toString());

            Integer no_of_items = Integer.parseInt(mvghp.getNo_of_items(), 10);

            mvghp.setGroup_rate( (row[0].toString().equals("GR")) ? mct.getRate_for_green_coupons()
                                                                  : mct.getRate_for_pink_coupons()  );

            Integer variable_payment = no_of_items * Integer.parseInt( mvghp.getGroup_rate(), 10);
            sumTotalOfPayment = sumTotalOfPayment + variable_payment;

            mvghp.setVariable_payment(variable_payment.toString());

            session.save(mvghp);
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }

        Query query2 = session.createSQLQuery(
"select m.pooja_name, count(*) as no_of_items from t_pooja_booking t inner join m_pooja_detail m on t.pooja_id=m.pooja_id where date_format(t.pooja_date, '%Y%m')= :string and m.pooja_name in ('A','B' ) group by m.pooja_name")
                                             .addScalar("m.pooja_name", Hibernate.STRING)
                                             .addScalar("no_of_items", Hibernate.STRING)
                                             .setString("string", ccyymm);

        ScrollableResults results1 = query2.scroll();

        while ( results1.next() )
        {
            Object[] row = results1.get();

            mvghp.setMvhpgroup(new Monthlyvariablecompid(mvhp.getMvhp().getVariable_monthly_month()
                                , mvhp.getMvhp().getVariable_monthly_ccyy()
                              , row[0].toString())
                              );

            mvghp.setNo_of_items(row[1].toString());
            Integer no_of_items = Integer.parseInt(mvghp.getNo_of_items(), 10);

            mvghp.setGroup_rate((row[0].toString().equals("A"))?mct.getRate_for_108_vadamalas_cook()
                                                                             :mct.getRate_for_51_vadamalas_cook() );

            Integer variable_payment = no_of_items * Integer.parseInt(mvghp.getGroup_rate() , 10) ;
            sumTotalOfPayment = sumTotalOfPayment + variable_payment;

            mvghp.setVariable_payment(variable_payment.toString());

            session.save(mvghp);
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }


        mvhp.setTotal_variable_payment(sumTotalOfPayment.toString());
        session.save(mvhp);

        tx.commit();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        if(tx!=null)
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling session.save(mvghp), session.flush(), and session.clear() for each iteration through the loop is at best inefficient, and seems like it might be part of where your confusion stems from.

Let's go back to basics.  In Hibernate, each object loosely represents a row in the top-level table, plus the rows in the child tables that join to that one top-level row.  (Yes, there are exceptions, and yes, this is an oversimplification, but for someone new to Hibernate, it's a good working model to help you get your feet under you.)  That means that if you're going to end up with multiple rows in the table at the end (e.g. once per loop iteration), you should be ending up with multiple objects, one per row.  What you're doing (reusing the same one Hibernate object) goes against this; if I've understood your use case correctly, you should be creating a new Hibernate POJO (short for Plain Old Java Object) for each iteration through the loop.

Second, a POJO can be either persistent (your Hibernate session is aware of the object and will save changes to the database when your transaction gets flushed or closed) or transient (Hibernate doesn't know anything about this object, and won't save changes to the database).  Calling save() makes a transient object persistent (and has no effect on a POJO that's already persistent!); it's probably the worst-named method in the Hibernate API, and should be called makePersistent() instead of save(), because it doesn't actually save the object to the database.  Rather, it makes it persistent, so that it will *eventually* get saved to the database.  The call to clear() does the opposite: it takes all persistent objects in the session and makes them non-persistent, discarding all changes in the process, and it has no effect on POJOs that are already transient.

And flush() just forces Hibernate to write out all changes to persistent objects to the database; Hibernate is free to do this at any other time if it chooses to, and is guaranteed to do it when the session's transaction commits, but calling flush() forces it to do that right now.  But it doesn't commit the transaction, so a) you'll still lose those changes if the transaction is rolled back, and b) you won't see the changes in the database until the transaction commits, if you're looking via something like SQLPlus.  It's generally only useful when you want to push your changes from your POJOs to the database before you run a SQL-based query where you want it to consider the changes you just made, or where you have very large batched transactions where you want to flush your changes for one batch and then garbage-collect those POJOs so you don't run out of memory before the transaction completes, and it's certainly not necessary for where you say you are with Hibernate.

So when you call save(), then flush(), and then clear() for each POJO, what you're doing is making that one object persistent, then forcing the database to write its data to the DB, and then making it transient.  Then you make changes to its data during the next loop iteration, and when you make it persistent again Hibernate thinks it's a new object (as you want) and saves a new row to the database.  This works, but all the flushing is inefficient (and confusing to people familiar with Hibernate), and you'd get the same behavior by just creating N instances of your POJO type and calling save() on each one (no flush(), no clear()), with better performance and less confusion.

Also, clear() is a bit of a sledgehammer; it removes *all* POJOs from your Hibernate session, which could cause very unexpected behavior for any code that was expecting to be able to change those objects and have those changes persisted.  (Your call to flush() just before will ensure that any changes that have already been made get persisted, but will do nothing to ensure that future changes do.)  It also means that anytime Hibernate needs to retrieve any of those objects, it has to go all the way back to the database instead of pulling them from the session's cache, which is inefficient.  If you really wanted to use the approach you've got here (and I've done it occasionally, such as in situations where I wanted to end up with many objects persisted but couldn't reasonably construct a new object for each, so I reused the same object, changing its properties while it's transient and not tracking those changes and then briefly making it persistent so it'll write the "new" object to the database), the method you'd probably want to use is the evict() method, which lets you remove just one Hibernate object from the cache.  But I want to stress that even evict() is more of an experts-only feature, and you don't need it (and shouldn't be using it) in most scenarios, including the ones in your example.

Hopefully that helps you get further with your understanding of Hibernate...